# Radial (not Polar!) planimeter theory...

Tags: calculus

I am investigating the theory of a *radial* (**not** a polar) planimeter - when tracing a closed contour with the "pole" of the device *outside* of the contour (normally, the "pole" would be inside the contour).

This has led me to this horrible expression below, whilst trying to evaluate a line integral - and I have been unable to progress beyond it...

$$
\int_0^{2\pi } \frac{r\ldotp \mathrm{cos}\left(t\right)\ldotp \left(a+r\ldotp \mathrm{cos}\left(t\right)\right)}{\sqrt{{\left(a+r\ldotp \mathrm{cos}\left(t\right)\right)}^2 +{\left(b+r\ldotp \mathrm{sin}\left(t\right)\right)}^2 }}+\frac{r\ldotp \mathrm{sin}\left(t\right)\ldotp \left(b+r\ldotp \mathrm{sin}\left(t\right)\right)}{\sqrt{{\left(a+r\ldotp \mathrm{cos}\left(t\right)\right)}^2 +{\left(b+r\ldotp \mathrm{sin}\left(t\right)\right)}^2 }}\mathrm{dt}
$$
Does anyone have any suggestions about how I might proceed with the solution to this? (Wolfram times out and so does the rudimentary symbolic processor which I have access to).

I therefore reverted to a numerical approach and found that the results appear to be physically plausible (also nicely confirmed by measurements using an actual instrument), but I want to find the *analytical solution* as this will obviously provide much more insight into the underlying process. Of course, I realise that there may not be an analytical solution...

Thanks for looking.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the contour being considered is a circle of radius r, with a centre at (a,b). The "pole" of the device is assumed to be at (0,0).

Comment: This doesn't look like the right integral; what's the original expression you're using to find the area?

Comment: I'm not finding the area - a _radial_ planimeter doesn't do that. When the pole is inside the contour it will measure the mean value of the contour (or a function of it) relative to the 0,0 point. The question I am interested in is - what does it measure when the pole is outside the shape? Of course, it may not be anything meaningful...!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is indeed the correct integral you want to evaluate, you can do the following:

Since your "pole" lies outside the contour we can work from
$$
\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = c > r > 0
$$
where $c$ is the distance from the origin to the point $(a,b)$ and $r$ the radius of the circles of the contour. Expanding the numerators and denominators we get
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{
r^2 + a r \cos t + b r \sin t
}{
\sqrt{r^2 + a^2 + b^2 + 2 a r \cos t + 2 b r \sin t}
} d t,
$$
where I already used that $\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t = 1$. Since we also can use that 
$a \cos t + b \sin t = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin(t + \phi) = c\sin(t + \phi) $ for $\phi = \arctan a/b$, the integral becomes simpler
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{r^2 + r c \sin (t+\phi)}{\sqrt{r^2 + c^2 + 2 r c \sin (t+\phi)}} d t.
$$
While the integration is over a whole period, the angular shift $\phi$ can be discarded, and we get
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{r^2 + r c \sin t}{\sqrt{r^2 + c^2 + 2 r c \sin t}} d t
$$
An alternative way to look at this result is to rotate the frame of reference such that the point $(a,b)$ lies on the $y$-axis at a distance $c$ from the origin.

There are only two integrals to be evaluated:
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + q \sin t}} d t
$$
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{1 + q \sin t}} d t
$$
with $0 < q = 2 r c/\sqrt{r^2+c^2}<1$. These give rise to the complete elliptic integral functions $E(..)$ and $K(..)$, and will result in
$$
(c-r) \left[ E\left(\frac{-4 c r}{(c-r)^2}\right) - K\left(\frac{4 c r}{(c+r)^2}\right) \right] + (c+r) \left[ E\left(\frac{4 c r}{(c+r)^2}\right) - K\left(\frac{-4 c r}{(c-r)^2}\right) \right]
$$